# How to get setting information before booting Android devices like in BIOS?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, kernel, bootloader

Is there any method by which we could get the system information before booting android OS.

Like wise in PC/laptop, we can get into BIOS setting before booting and get the system information. Do Android devices have such thing?

If yes, how can I go through before booting? Is there BIOS like setup in android? Shed some light.

Comment: Can you state what you want to achieve? Just see that information, or adjust something -- on every boot, occasionally -- and if, what to change? This would allow for a more precise answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is no BIOS type thing in Android, although there is the [Logcat](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/logcat.html) and DMESG.

There is [an app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.chainfire.livelogcat.lite) on Google Play that allows you to change your boot animation to show you the *live* logcat as your device boots.

If you want the System Info, as per your question, you would just have to Google your device, or use a site such as [GSM Arena](http://www.gsmarena.com) to lookup your devices hardware.

Comment: I search and find that dmesg command = get kernel log and logcat command = get android system log both show the log related to system. Is there any thing which install before installing OS like in PC system i.e BIOS. If we have to install other OS in mobile how it detect it.

Comment: No, I said that.

Comment: I got something that is SPL / Bootloader(Second Program Loader) is like BIOS on a computer . What is SPL and can it work like BIOS ?

Answer (score 0):

BIOS stands for Basic Input Output System. It is the computer system that does the very basic set up of computerized system. Some BIOS's can be altered by the user and some can not. Take an HP computer vs. a custom built machine with Asus motherboard for example.

In regards to a smart phone, there is a "BIOS" however you can not change it or update it, etc. It is hard coded into a chip on the phone.

The bootloader is the second step in the boot process. Many Linux machines use GRUB or LILO, etc. I imagine that SPL is the bootloader used by a smartphone.

I am not including i-phone type equipment in this explanation. I-phones run on magic and Skittles!! LOL

Comment: Could you support your answer with sources, or is that your own experience/imagination?